# wget_ how to download pdfs only from href url and text <&#187; PDF>?

Tags: wget

there are multiple .pdfs with same file name.

for example: 61c56fb615b7b3.00271374.pdf
`<a href='./admin/Uploads/Files/61c56fb615b7b3.00271374.pdf' target=_blank style='padding-right:33px;'>&#187; PDF</a> &#187; doi: <a href='./admin/Uploads/Files/61c56fb615b7b3.00271374.pdf' target="blank" style='padding-right:33px;'>10.31838/jcr.07.13.188</a>`

i want to avoid download pdf of
doi and doi url

how do i download only links of urls which end with .pdf **and** text of link as `"&#187; PDF"`.

the above example is from journal website: https://www.jcreview.com/issue.php?volume=Volume%207%20&issue=Issue-13&year=2020